# how to solve the illegal reference error from verilog

Tags: verilog

I keep getting error messages.
I don't know what is problem

** Error: C:/intelFPGA/sample(1)/minute.v(25): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "seconds".

this is my error message.

```
module minute(
    clk,  //Clock with 1 Hz frequency    [Clk_1sec]
    reset,     //active high reset
    seconds,
    minutes);

//What are the Inputs?
    input clk; 
    input reset;
    input seconds;
//What are the Outputs?
    output [5:0] minutes;
 
//Internal variables.
   
    reg [5:0] minutes;
   

   //Execute the always blocks when the Clock or reset inputs are
    //changing from 0 to 1(positive edge of the signal)
    always @(posedge(clk) or posedge(reset))
   
            if(seconds == 6'd60) begin //check for max value of sec
                seconds = 6'd0;  //reset seconds
                minutes = minutes + 2'b1; //increment minutes
               
    end    

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

`seconds` is your input. It's being driven somewhere outside module `minute`. You can not modify it here.

```
            if(seconds == 6'd60) begin //check for max value of sec
                seconds = 6'd0;  //reset seconds                   // <----- HERE
                minutes = minutes + 2'b1; //increment minutes
               
    end
```

Comment: so then,, How can I modify seconds 60-> 0 ...? I can't find ..

Comment: If you want to modify this `seconds`, you cannot do it here. Do it where `seconds` is driven. Or you may get a copy of `seconds` by latching it to 6 D flip-flops, and then modify the copied version in module `minute`. However this way, you're actually modifying a separate circuit device.